# MVC Hangfire Authorization Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, hangfire

I want to inject to Hangfire AuthorizationFilter  my custom serice and do something with it an i face problem my service is always null.

Owin startup class :

```
 public class Startup
{

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app )
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .UseSqlServerStorage("SomeContext")
            .UseNinjectActivator(new Bootstrapper().Kernel);

        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions { AuthorizationFilters = new[] { new RestrictiveAuthorizationFilter() } });
        app.UseHangfireServer();
    }
}
```

Custom filter :

```
public class RestrictiveAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{

    [Inject]
    public IUserService _userService { get; set; }

    public bool Authorize(IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment)
    {

      //do something with _userService but it is always null

      return true;
    }
}
```

Ninject kernel :

```
 private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind(x => { x.From(typeof(BookService).Assembly).SelectAllClasses().EndingWith("Service").BindDefaultInterface(); });
        kernel.Bind<LibraryDBContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IBackgroundJobClient>().To<BackgroundJobClient>();
    }
```

I don't see my error could you help me ?

Comment: you'll need to tell ninject to build up this instance, which is usually done with `kernel.BindFilter<RestrictiveAuthorizationFilter>(FilterScope.Action, null);`. However I don't know how you have to apply it to the Hangfire Dashboard.

Comment: After you do what @BatteryBackupUnit said about registering, change `AuthorizationFilters = new[] { new RestrictiveAuthorizationFilter() }` to something like `AuthorizationFilters = new[] { injectedFilter }` and take `RestrictiveAuthorizationFilter injectedFilter` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the kernel as an argument to RestrictiveAuthorizationFilter constructor and ask for the IUserService.

```
public class RestrictiveAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter 
{   
    public IUserService _userService { get; set; }

    public RestrictiveAuthorizationFilter(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _userService = kernel.Get<IUserService>()
    }

    public bool Authorize(IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment)
    {

      //do something with _userService but it is always null

      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but there's an upvote waiting for you if you edit.  
This is an example of "Service Location" as an [anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)  Instead of taking an `IKernel` as an argument, you should be taking the thing you actually want - the `IUserService`.  (This is all for "constructor injection," which is not even strictly necessary, given that the question already uses a `[Inject]` attribute for "property injection.")  The critical pieces to make this work are in the comments from me and @BatteryBackupUnit

Comment: Filter attribute instances are cached indefinitely per action, effectively making them singletons. This makes them unsuited for DI since the attribute’s dependencies will be accidentally promoted to singleton as well, which can cause all sorts of concurrency issues.

Since DI is not an option here, an other mechanism is advised. There are basically two options here. Which one is best depends on the amount of filter attributes your application needs. If the number of attributes is limited (to a few), the simplest solution is to revert to the Service Locator pattern within your attributes.